# Rewriting nginx.conf when converting docker-compose to Kubernetes using Kompose?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, docker-compose, kompose

I am quite new to `Kubernetes` and I have been struggling to migrate my current *docker-compose* environment to Kubernetes...

I converted my `docker-compose.yml` to Kubernetes manifests using **kompose**.

So far, I can access each pod individually but it seems like I have some issues to get those pods to communicate each other.. My Nginx pod can not access my app pod

My `docker-compose.yml` is something like below

```
version: '3.3'
services:

  myapp:
    image: my-app
    build: ./docker/
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: app
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - mnt:/mnt
    env_file:
      - .env


  mynginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    build: ./docker/
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    stdin_open: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    user: root
```

My `Nginx.conf` is something like below

```
server{
    listen 80;
    index index.html index.htm;
    root   /mnt/volumes/statics/;


location /myapp {

  proxy_pass http://myapp/index;

  proxy_redirect     off;
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

I understand that `docker-compose` enables containers to communicate each other through service names (**myapp** and **mynginx** in this case). Could somebody tell me what I need to do to achieve the same thing in Kubernetes?

Comment: What do you want to do with Nginx here? Do you want to use it as a LoadBalancer/Reverse proxy?

Comment: You need Kubernetes Service objects.  In other Kompose examples I've seen those automatically generated.  Rather than leaning on Kompose, you might look through the documentation on https://kubernetes.io/ and try to write out the YAML files corresponding to this to better understand the concepts; you should need two Deployments, two Services, and one ConfigMap (depending a little bit on what the `volumes:` is intended to do).

Comment: @vjdhama Yes, I would like to use it as a reverse proxy.

Comment: @DavidMaze
Thank you for your response. Yes, Kompose did create services for me. It turned out that what I missed was docker-compose.overwrite file (apparently kompose just ignores overwrite.yml). However, I am again stuck with how to convert "build: ./docker" in the docker-compose. Does anyone has any insight on this?

Comment: Kubernetes won't build images for you (among other things that Docker Compose does).  You need a Docker image registry, and you'll need to `docker-compose push` your images to it before Kubernetes can run them.

Comment: @DavidMaze
Understood. I just tried to use the images that docker-compose created and it seems to be working. Thank you very much for your swift help!

Comment: If your issue has been resolved with the suggestion made in comments- could you post it as an answer? It will be more visible and might help others who will encounter similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Kompose did create services for me. It turned out that what I missed was docker-compose.overwrite file (apparently kompose just ignores overwrite.yml).